# Twitter share button bigger or smaller than G+ and Facebook

Tags: button, twitter, facebook-like, share

This problem has been bugging me for literally months. We've got (very effective) Facebook and G+ buttons horizontally aligned on several pages, but we've had to leave off Twitter because the Twitter button's height, which gives you two size options in their button builder, is either bigger or smaller than the other two buttons, which are both 24px tall. It looks like Twitter's button are 20px or 26px. I've attached a screenshot for an example.

If we go small size twitter, it's obviously quite a bit smaller than the other two buttons and looks very tacky (same thing for large size). I've searched EVERYWHERE for an answer to this. I was hoping to use what Twitter's already got, but should I just custom make a button? If so, is there any easy way to get the count still?

I can't find any good workaround to this problem (I've read the documentation at https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button) AND I can't seem to find anyone else with it, not on SO not anywhere, so I'm wondering if I'm just missing something painfully obvious and somebody ends up with an accepted answer for telling me how I'm an idiot...

**SCREENSHOT**
http://sphotos.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash3/553477_10150822852373097_614203096_9759982_910737829_n.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Twitter doesn't offer 24px height buttons, however you can make all three providers be 20px tall.

Facebook: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/ (use "button_count" style).
Twitter: https://twitter.com/about/resources/buttons#tweet (don't use the "Large" checkbox).
G+: https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/+1button/ ("medium" size)

All 3 providers also have a "Tall" format, that is similar across them if you enable the count option for each of them.